# Mootools slider adjustments

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am new to mootools. I have joomla site with MooSlider:

```
var MooSlider = new Class({
initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = Object.extend({
        container: null,
        slides: null,
        navs:null,
        transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut,
        effectDuration: 500,
        fromTop: 500,
        topDist: 100,
        slideDelay: 5000
    }, options || {});

    if(!$(this.options.container)) return;
    this.start();   
},

start: function(){
    this.elements = $(this.options.container).getElements(this.options.slides);
    this.navs = $(this.options.container).getElements(this.options.navs);
    this.currentElement = 0;

    this.elements.each(function(elem, i){
        var nav = this.navs[i];

        if(i==this.currentElement){
            nav.addClass('selected');               
        }
        elem.setStyles({
            'position':'absolute',
            'top':0,
            'left':0,
            'opacity':( i==this.currentElement ? 1 : 0 )
        });

        this.elements[i]['fx'] = new Fx.Styles(elem, {
            duration:this.options.effectDuration, 
            wait:false, 
            transition:this.options.transition
        });
        this.elements[i]['nav'] = nav;

        elem.addEvents({
            'mouseenter': function(){
                $clear(this.period);
            }.bind(this),
            'mouseleave': function(){
                if( this.options.slideDelay )
                    this.period = this.rotate.periodical(this.options.slideDelay, this);
            }.bind(this)            
        });

        nav.addEvent('click', function(event){

            if(this.currentElement==i) return;
            new Event(event).stop();                
            $clear(this.period);
            this.changeSlide(i);
            if( this.options.slideDelay )
                this.period = this.rotate.periodical(this.options.slideDelay, this);

        }.bind(this));

    }.bind(this));
    if( this.options.slideDelay )
        this.period = this.rotate.periodical(this.options.slideDelay, this);

},

rotate: function(){
    var i = this.currentElement+1 < this.elements.length ? this.currentElement+1 : 0;
    this.changeSlide(i);
},

changeSlide: function(i){
    //$(this.options.navigationContainer).addClass('preload');
    var cEl = this.currentElement;
    this.elements[this.currentElement]['fx'].start({'opacity':0, 'left':1500});

    this.elements[i]['fx'].set({'left':0});
    this.elements[i]['fx'].start({'opacity':1, 'top':[500,0]}).chain(function(){
        //$(this.options.navigationContainer).removeClass('preload');           
    }.bind(this));

    this.elements[this.currentElement]['nav'].removeClass('selected');
    this.elements[i]['nav'].addClass('selected');

    this.currentElement = i;
}})
```

This is how it used on page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    new MooSlider({
        container:'topslider',
        slides:'.slide',
        navs:'.navigator ul li',

        effectDuration: 1000,
        fromTop:500,
        topDist:500,
        slideDelay: 3000        });
})
```

The page url is http://www.miltonwebsitedesign.ca

You can see slider on top of the page. Each slide consists of picture at the left and description at the right.

What I need is to make slides work the same way, but the left side picture must not appear current way, it needs to fade in, when the slide is loaded, not appear, but fade in.

Description text slides and then at the left picture appears.

The structure of each slide is:

```
<div class='slide'>
   <div class="yjsquare">
      <div class="yjsquare_in">
         <img src='src here' alt=''/><h1>H1 text here</h1><p>description here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Will be happy to hear solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this class is not well written as in, it does not allow for events like `onStart` and `onComplete` to be passed. the logical approach would be to modify the `changeSlide` method to fire some events:

```
// add
var el = this.elements[i]['fx'];
this.fireEvent("start", el);

// use el as reference...
el.start({'opacity':1, 'top':[500,0]}).chain(function(){
        //$(this.options.navigationContainer).removeClass('preload');           
    // add
    this.fireEvent("complete", el);
}.bind(this));
```

Make sure that your class also implements Events (which in 1.12 is done like so, if memory serves):

```
MooSlider.implement(new Events);
```

you are using a mix of 1.12 and 1.2+ code which is odd. In any case, if you do have 1.2 (joomla usually is not prior to 1.6) then instead add this into the class declaration:

```
Implements: [Events],
```

this allows you to add some callback logic upon instigating the class:

```
new MooSlider({
    container:'topslider',
    slides:'.slide',
    navs:'.navigator ul li',

    effectDuration: 1000,
    fromTop:500,
    topDist:500,
    slideDelay: 3000,
    onStart: function(el) {
        el.getElement("img").setOpacity(0); // hide it during animation
    },
    onComplete: function(el) {
        el.fade(1); // fade it in when done
    }
});
```

you should really implement Options too and use `this.setOptions(options)` instead of your current $extend.

p.s. the onStart and onComplete code callbacks are examples, you may need to tweak this to suit your html and UI preferences.

Comment: +1 i wish i read this post before i made my Mootools Video class